# ArrayList check for combination of two object values at the same index

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on an ATM simulation program. Currently I'm working on methods to verify the user input. I have an arraylist with bank card objects these objects consist of 3 variables I want
to check if a given reknr and pasnr combination is equal with any reknr and pasnr combination in my arraylist with the bankcard objects. If the arraylist contains the given combination the method has to return true, otherwise it has to return false.

```
 public static boolean reknrpasnrCheckOke(String reknr,String pasnr){
  for (int i=0; i<rekpaspin.size(); i++){
  if (rekpaspin.get(i).reknr.equals(reknr) && rekpaspin.get(i).pasnr.equals(pasnr))
    return true;
  }
  return false;
  }
 }
```

It doesn't matter what the input is it always returns false, how to solve this?

Edit::

I forgot an { after the if so I changed the code to:

```
 public static boolean reknrpasnrCheckOke(String reknr,String pasnr){
 for (int i=0; i<rekpaspin.size(); i++){
 if (rekpaspin.get(i).reknr.equals(reknr) && rekpaspin.get(i).pasnr.equals(pasnr)){
 return true;
 }
 }
 return false;
 }
```

But still the same problem.

Comment: what is stored in the arraylist?? Strings to compare to the passed parameters?

Comment: A good formatting will help you see the problem right away.

Comment: Not sure if typo or not, but you are missing a `{` after your if statement.

Comment: If you have always a combination of two and your name is the primary key, you could use a `Map<String,String>` to solve this a bit easier imo.

Answer (score 4):

You are only checking the first item in the list.  If it's not matching, then you immediately return `false` without checking the rest of the items.

Move the `return false;` after the end of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate equality of objects by means other that memory reference, you have to override the `equals()` method and `hashcode()` method of you `rekpaspin` class.

Also, you should not use an `ArrayList<>` and search it each time. Consider using a `Set` or `HashMap`

Answer (score 0):

First, as stated by @rgettman, if the first 'if' check doesn't match, you automatically return false, so it needs to arranged better.

However, in this case you probably want to use a boolean flag. It should be set to false until the case matches, in which case you would set the flag to true. Outside the loop you would return the flag.